# What's superscripting only numbers on this web page?

Tags: css, numbers

Working on some self-education for a class I'm taking, and messing around with free online templates to try to understand what makes them tick.

I can't figure this out: all numbers -- and *only* numbers -- are superscripted on this web page: http://adequatewebsites.com/dev/gumba-bookstore/index.html. I've tried looking at it in Inspect View in Chrome, and I can't see anything there...

Page template originally downloaded from http://www.free-css.com/free-css-templates/page210/gumba.

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce the problem here. Perhaps it's the font you're seeing.

Comment: It's the `font-feature-settings: "kern", "liga", "frac", "pnum";` declarations, specifically the frac feature.

Comment: Thanks -- I was looking for superscripting being applied to numbers alone, which is where my brain was getting hung up.

Comment: Also -- since the problem's been fixed, there's nothing left to 'see' here if anyone looks, so I'm all for votes to close and/or delete this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the [`font-feature-settings`](https://helpx.adobe.com/typekit/using/open-type-syntax.html) that applies directly to font itself.

In this page it's `font-feature-settings: "kern", "liga", "frac", "pnum";`

`liga` - Disable common ligatures, usually on by default
`frac` - Enable automatic fractions
`pnum` - Replaces numeral glyphs set on uniform (tabular) widths with corresponding glyphs set on glyph-specific (proportional) widths
`kern` - Adjusts the amount of space between glyphs

Comment: Thank you -- I was looking for sup or other line-height and font-size declarations; it never occurred to me to look for frac.